# Connecting a laptop to a shared printer on a desktop PC (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, printer

I have 2 computers:

1. A laptop (with windows 7 x64)
2. A desktop PC (with windows 7 x32)

I am trying to connect the laptop to the shared printer on the desktop PC

I should mention that I previously stopped some service from the administration panel of the control panel (but have brought them all back - I think)

Here's some of the stuff I have tried:

1. Setting static IP's for both of the computers
2. Connection to the desktop pc from the "Run" command on the laptop device using the desktop computer name (just to check that the connection works - and it gives me a "cannot access" error)
3. Restarting both PC's and their "Print Spooler" services
4. I also tried to share files and folders using the HomeGroup feature and using the networking feature of Windows (no success)
5. I mapped my network on both PC's using Windows Network Mapping Tool - and all seems alright
6. I have tried to reset netsh using cmd

None of these things fixed the problem. What are some good next steps?

Comment: I assume the printer is shared - also, did you install it on the 64bit machine, if so you may have used 64bit drivers which the 32bit machine won't be able to work with

Comment: How are you connecting the computers? Can the computers Ping each other?  Have you tried with the firewalls (temporarily) disabled?

Comment: @ Dave Rook i have 64bit drivers installed. @techie007 I already tried to disable anti-viruses and firewalls on both computers (I disabled Windows firewall + avast + malwarebyte). btw guys thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 2):

First off, you need to establish connectivity to the host computer -- you should be able to display its shared files, printers, et al.

From "Network and Sharing Center" click "View computers and devices, and make sure the host computer shows up.  Then double-click the host computer in the resulting display and you should see the shared files and printers.  If the printer you want is marked as sharable on the host then you should see it (though you may have to click "Printers" first).

Right-mouse-button on the printer and select "connect".  The printer should be "installed" on your box.

You may, in some cases, have to manually download and install the print driver for the printer onto your box.

If the above procedure doesn't work, describe what it *does* do.

Comment: By clicking "View computers and devices" I can see the Host (the desktop pc) but I cannot access it (I get an error "Network Error Code: 0x80070035 Windows cannot access").. but when doing the same on the Host - I can see the files on the client (laptop)

Comment: @dinbrca -- OK, you need to resolve that problem first, and it's basically unrelated to getting your printer connected.  First make sure sharing is enabled on the host printer:  In Network and Sharing Center set `Network discovery` to ON and `Printer sharing` to ON.  If you still have a problem then there's something wrong with your network setup.

Comment: I already had those stuff on ON in both of the computers.. by the way what do you mean I have something wrong with my network setup?

Comment: @dinbrca -- Normally you'd have both computers connected to a router, so you wouldn't need to dink with thinks like static IPs.  Are both boxes connected to the same router?  Are the both in the same workgroup?

Comment: They are both connected to the same router (as I said.. I mapped my network and all seemed fine..), also they both on same workgroup

Comment: @dinbrca -- Then I'd suggest you consider it a Windows sharing problem, not a printing problem.  Perhaps if you can temporarily get another laptop into the network you can determine which side is in error.

Comment: I already have an older laptop - which works just fine - but there is a big difference between those two computers - the old one have Windows XP, which means the problem is probably on the new laptop (the one with Windows 7)

Comment: No one got an answer?

Comment: @dinbrca -- You have a Windows sharing problem.  Open a new thread with that question.